# SQL ERROR IS Operand type clash: int is incompatible with date

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
CREATE TABLE prime_emp (
emp_id INT not null,
first_name VARCHAR(14) not null,
 last_name VARCHAR(14) not null,
 birth_date DATE not null,
 father_name VARCHAR (14) not null,
 mather_name VARCHAR (14),
joing_date DATE not null,
departmen VARCHAR(14) not null,
Primary key (emp_id)
)
select * from prime_emp
insert into prime_emp
(emp_id,first_name,last_name,birth_date,father_name,mather_name, joing_date,departmen)
values(01,'Ashish','Soni',15-07-1990,'Suman','Usha',28-10-2013,'Media');
```

But I got an error message:

> Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Line 13
>   Operand type clash: int is incompatible with date

Comment: *Unquoted* 15-07-1990 is 15 minus 7 minus 1990 which is a number, not a date, quote all date values. (preferably in a non-ambiguous format like yyyy-mm-dd)

Answer (score 0):

Write date field as following pattern {d 'yyyy-mm-dd'}

Another appoint: emp_id = 1 not 01, because emp_id is int so 0 has lost.

Try this:

```
insert into prime_emp
(emp_id,first_name,last_name,birth_date,father_name,mather_name, joing_date, departmen)
values
(1,'Ashish','Soni',{d '1990-07-15'},'Suman','Usha',{d '2013-10-28'},'Media');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should **give quotes around date values**. Other wise it will be treated as an
arithmetic expression.

So change your `insert` query to

```
insert into prime_emp
(emp_id,first_name,last_name,birth_date,father_name,mather_name, joing_date,departmen)
values(01,'Ashish','Soni','15-07-1990','Suman','Usha','28-10-2013','Media');
```